# Can someone help me flip this Actionscript 3 graphic?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics

```
newPlacement = new Block();
        newPlacement.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        newPlacement.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 25, 25, 9);
        newPlacement.graphics.endFill();
        newPlacement.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        newPlacement.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,25);
        newPlacement.graphics.endFill();
        blockHolder.addChild(newPlacement);
```

Here is code I am using in Flash to draw a square object on the stage that is jagged on the left and rounded on the right. Can anyone help me figure out how to code the flipped image of this (a square object that is rounded on the left and jagged on the right). Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a visual example? Put a link online (eg: **[imgur.com](http://www.imgur.com)**)

Comment: newPlacement.scaleX = -1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If the posted answer works for you **mark it as correct (Green Tick)** or else **upvote it** as useful. Just a polite way to show thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is basically adding a rounded rectangle and then placing a regular rectangle on top of that. The regular rectangle is not as wide, so the rounded rectangle doesn't get covered up on the right side.

[image: RoundedRectangle]

---

### Option 1: change relative x position of regular rectangle

All you need to do is place the regular rectangle 15 units to the right. So instead of this:

```
newPlacement.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,25);
```

do this:

```
newPlacement.graphics.drawRect(15,0,10,25);
```

---

### Option 2: flip the object

But I still like this best:

```
newPlacement.scaleX = -1;
```

Personal preference, though.